# To calculate income gap: use log income or original value

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I am tring to calculate a measure of income gap of my individual-level sample (by group) and use it in regressions. What I want to do is to divide the mean income of individuals whose imcome are above 70th percentile (top 30%) by that of individuals whose income are at lowest 30%. What I am not sure is:

(1) whether I should use the log income or the original value of income to calculate the percentile?

(2) should I just simpliy calculate P70/P30, instead of (mean income above 70th percentile)/mean income below 70th percentile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see, then that makes more sense. Firstly, I would do chi square test for association to see if certain income gaps are associated with fertility desire. I would not do regression since we're dealing with two outcomes (yes for desire for fertility, or no for desire) which will come out as proportions and will be pretty annoying if your dealing with that in a regression. If you're having an issue with data, then that's a larger issue. If I were in your shoes I would get samples within my city/area instead of finding data online. Trust me, I've had a lot of trouble when trying to find good sources of data that accurately support my claim. I would also still just use the ratio of (70-100%)/(0-70%), or whatever income groups you decide. Then I would group those ratios in proportions. Like if the ratio came out to be 4.56, then it would be out in the group for 4-5, etc. However this would require a lot of data and sampling, and depending on how dedicated you are, will be quite difficult.

Unbiased data is one of the hardest things to get. Sampling bias is impossible to avoid, especially when the people who respond to your survey often lie. If there's anything I can do right now, it's to wish you good luck. You got this :)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is really insightful, but as an economist, I have to build the arguments based on regression results, so I am trying to use some other indirect measures.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are doing a regression, you want to find a correlation between (what i'm assuming is) location of the individual and income. You have no reason to do μ(70%-100%)/μ(0%-70%).This ratio tells you nothing except for the correlation between percentile and mean income, which, is useless since the percentile already tells you that. In both your questions 1) and 2), I would not use log and I would reconstruct the entire procedure for finding a correlation gap.

If you want to find evidence of an income gap (assuming it's between different locations/area). I highly recommend doing a **chi square test of homogeneity** while assuming p1=p2=p3 etc. If you're dealing with numbers, then just group numbers into proportions like $0-$50,000 as p1. You should use alpha=0.05 as well.

If i'm completely missing what you're trying to do, please tell me. Im a little bit confused as to why you are doing that.

Comment: I regress individual's fertility desire on the income gap between upper and lower class of his province, so for each province I am trying to calculate the income gap using individual's family income. After playing with various measures I can't get the estimates I want, it's probably due to the sampling bias of the data. I want to show that larger income gap is associated with lower fertility desire. But rich people belonging to upper class can barely be surveyed, so  the estimates show the opposite, that larger income gap is associated with higher fertility desire.